# After sorting an array of objects in JavaScript, how would I display the opposite way of sorting? (update)

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am new to JavaScript. I am currently at obj with functions. I have this code:

```js
var tableIn = [
  {name: "name", itemsBought: 15},
  {name: "Courtney Act", itemsBought: 20},
  {name: "Bianca del Rio", itemsBought: 13}
];
//going to use loops to limit input to specific words
var question1= prompt("By what to sort? type in : name or items bought").toLowerCase();
var question2= prompt("How to sort? up/down:").toLowerCase(); 


function myFunction(question1, question2) {
tableIn.sort(function sortingA(x,y) {
    if (question2 == "up") {
      if (question1 == "name") {
        var ayy = x.name.toLowerCase();
        var byy = y.name.toLowerCase();
          if (ayy < byy) {return -1;}
          if (ayy > byy) {return 1;}
          return 0;
      } else {
        return x.itemsBought - y.itemsBought;
      }
    }
          });
tableIn.sort(function sortingD(x,y) {
  if (question2 == "down") {
    return -1 * sortingA(x,y);
  }
});
for (var idx = 0; idx < tableIn.length; idx++) {
  console.log(tableIn[idx].name + tableIn[idx].itemsBought);
}
}
myFunction(question1, question2);
```

How can i get the second part work? the reverse option of it

Comment: Yeah! You could have always ran a reverse loop. for `(var idx = tableIn.length - 1; idx >=0; idx--)`. Though you could have sorted it right in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reverse the order of a sorted array use [Array#reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) - `tableIn.revese()`.

To sort in the opposite direction, multiply the result of your sortAsc function by -1.

For example:

```js
var question1 = "name";

function sortAsc(x, y) {
    if (question1 == "name") {
      var ayy = x.name.toLowerCase();
      var byy = y.name.toLowerCase();
      if (ayy < byy) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (ayy > byy) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    } else {
      return x.itemsBought - y.itemsBought;
    }
}

function sortFunc(x, y) {
  var factor = question2 == "up" ? 1 : -1;
  return  factor * sortAsc(x, y);
}

var tableIn = [
  {name: "Alaska Thunder", itemsBought: 15},
  {name: "Courtney Act", itemsBought: 20},
  {name: "Bianca del Rio", itemsBought: 13}
];

var question2 = "up";
console.log('sortAsc: ', tableIn.sort(sortFunc));

var question2 = "down";
console.log('sortDesc: ', tableIn.sort(sortFunc));
```

Comment: But for descending order i would like "down" for input. where would i put the if statement for question2 == "down" ?

Comment: so what I am struggling with is to get the ascending order if question2 == "up" and descending order if question2 == "down".
I'm trying to work around **if** statements for that, but in your version the if statement i have need is inside the sortAsc function

Comment: You need to take the 1st `if` state out of the `sortAsc`, and use it decide if you want to multiply by 1 or -1. See updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 
    `return x.itemsBought - y.itemsBought;`

to
    `return (x.itemsBought - y.itemsBought) * -1;`